# Decoding JSON data types using knownsymbol/proxy approach

Tags: haskell

I am trying out the JSON decoding approach as laid out in a [blog post](http://aaronlevin.ca/post/111871447488/using-dataproxy-to-encode-types-in-your-json). Basically, we handle the data type for JSON encoding and decoding using `KnownSymbol` and `typefamilies`. So far so good. I tried out the code for [polymorphic containers](https://gist.github.com/aaronlevin/4aa22bd9c79997029167#file-06-polymorphic-containers-hs) but with actual decoding type (`Message String`) specified:

```
*Test> messageStringA
"{ \"payload\": {\"type\": \"string\", \"data\": \"cool\"} }"
*Test> decode messageStringA :: Maybe (Message String)
Just Message ( Payload string "cool" )
```

Now, I will like the decoding to work without specifying actual type - so, I added that code - instead of `Message String`, now we have `Message a` type:

```
decode1 :: (s ~ TypeKey a, KnownSymbol s, FromJSON a) => BL.ByteString -> Maybe (Message a)
decode1 = decode

testDecode :: (s ~ TypeKey a, KnownSymbol s, FromJSON a) => Maybe (Message a)
testDecode = decode1 messageStringA
```

Compilation is fine, but at run-time, I get this error in `ghci`:

```
*Test> :set -XFlexibleContexts
*Test> testDecode

<interactive>:5:1:
    No instance for (KnownSymbol (TypeKey a0))
      arising from a use of ‘it’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Will appreciate pointers on what I am doing wrong here. It looks to me that `ghci` is unable to print since there is no instance of `Show` for `KnownSymbol (TypeKey a)`.

Comment: If by "work without specifying an actual type" you mean you want the compiler to figure out which type it is, it simply isn't possible. Even if you have a representation of the type stored internally, you can't recover it. It will always have to be existentially quantified, no matter what you do with it. Even then, your show instance is `instance Show a => Show (Message a)` so you are obligated to produce a proof of `Show a` to show a message - nowhere do you store or compute such a proof (i.e. in the way that `KnownSymbol` is stored in `Message`).

Comment: @user2407038, yep, good point. That is what I was wondering about. It seems then I have to specify the exact type for decoding, instead of leaving it generic. So, this approach doesn't work when decoding messages over the network where we don't know what the actual type is, without looking at the `type` field.

Comment: The approach works - you just have to bite the existential quantification bullet so to speak. Dealing with existential quantification is clunky at times but it is the only way you can type information from runtime values. See my answer for a slightly modified approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of the issue is that you want to leave the type variables as parameters to allow class constraints on those parameters as needed, but you also want to have the type existentially quantified (because the type actually depends on a runtime value).

The simple thing you can exploit here is that the set of type satisfying `TypeKey x ~ a` is finite. Instead of representing this a type family, consider the following representation:

```
data TypeKeyOf (a :: *) (x :: Symbol) where 
  IntK :: Int `TypeKeyOf` "int" 
  StringK :: String `TypeKeyOf` "string"
```

Note that you can represent a generic finite map from e.g. `*` to `Symbol` but for simplicity lets keep it concrete.

You can now very easily write a function which "proves" various things about a type key:

```
type IsTypeKey a x = (ToJSON a, FromJSON a, KnownSymbol x)

isTypeKey :: TypeKeyOf a x -> (IsTypeKey a x => r) -> r 
isTypeKey IntK k = k 
isTypeKey StringK k = k 

keyOf :: TypeKeyOf a x -> Proxy x 
keyOf _ = Proxy
```

Crucially, your type class instances should not have contexts - your type information is all hidden.

```
instance ToJSON (TypeKeyOf a x) where 
  toJSON k = isTypeKey k (A.String . pack . symbolVal . keyOf $ k)

data SomeTypeKey = forall a x . TK (TypeKeyOf a x) 

instance FromJSON SomeTypeKey where 
    parseJSON (A.String s) 
      | s == "int" = return $ TK IntK 
      | s == "string" = return $ TK StringK 
    parseJSON _      = mzero
```

Again, the `Payload` type variables are existentially quantified. This doesn't mean you can do less with this type (in fact, you can do more).

```
data Payload where
  Payload :: a `TypeKeyOf` s -> a -> Payload 

instance ToJSON Payload where
    toJSON (Payload k a) = 
      object [ "type" .= k 
             , isTypeKey k $ "data" .= a
             ]

instance FromJSON Payload where
    parseJSON (Object v) = 
      (v .: "type") >>= \(TK q) -> isTypeKey q (Payload q <$> v .: "data") 
    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Note how at various points `isTypeKey` is used to prove that various things are instances of the appropriate classes.

If you try to write a show instance:

```
instance Show Payload where
    show (Payload k a) = isTypeKey k $ 
      "Payload " <> symbolVal (keyOf k) <> " " <> show a
```

You get `No instance for Show a ...`. This is fixed by adding the required constraint to `IsTypeKey`:

```
type IsTypeKey a x = (ToJSON a, FromJSON a, KnownSymbol x, Show a)
```

And now the type really is completely determined by the parse, but it is simply existentially quantified:

```
>decode "{\"type\": \"string\", \"data\": \"hello\"}" :: Maybe Payload
Just Payload string "hello"
>decode "{\"type\": \"int\", \"data\": 42}" :: Maybe Payload
Just Payload int 42
```

Note that if you "know" the actual type of the payload, you can still extract
that value in a type safe way, since you really know *everything* about the types, given that you can always find out precisely what they are.

```
class HasTypeKey a (x :: Symbol) | x -> a where 
  typeKey :: TypeKeyOf a x 

instance HasTypeKey Int "int" where typeKey = IntK 
instance HasTypeKey String "string" where typeKey = StringK 

typeKeyOf :: HasTypeKey a x => Proxy x -> TypeKeyOf a x 
typeKeyOf _ = typeKey 

sameKey :: TypeKeyOf a x -> TypeKeyOf a' x' -> Maybe ('(a, x) :~: '(a', x'))
sameKey IntK IntK = Just Refl 
sameKey StringK StringK = Just Refl 
sameKey _ _ = Nothing 

extractPayload :: HasTypeKey a x => Proxy x -> Payload -> Maybe a 
extractPayload t' (Payload t x) = fmap (\Refl -> x) $ sameKey t (typeKeyOf t')
```

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer this. Very helpful. Perhaps a gist with the whole code will also be very useful to have, if you still have it. Will help me tie the knots together.

Comment: The code in the answer is pretty much it, minus imports, which I just copied from your code. [Full code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5291f5a767c4bd12fac7f5cb8fc8bba1)